# Applying a mask to a spatial raster in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-sp, tmap

I would like to mask my background map using a shapefile representing a regional boundary. To do this I have read a spatial raster into Rstudio using read_osm

```
library(sp)
library(tmaptools)
HB_map <- spData::nz %>% 
  filter(Name=="Hawke's Bay") %>% 
  tmaptools::read_osm(type = "stamen-terrain")
```

I have then imported my shapefile

```
libary(sf)
Regional_boundary <- sf::st_read("regional_boundary.shp")
sf::st_crs(Regional_boundary)= 2193 
Regional_boundary_sf_poly <- sf::st_transform(Regional_boundary, 27200) %>% 
  sf::st_cast(to="POLYGON")
```

I have a number of GIS data sets so I re-project my raster so it is in the same projection as my GIS data (i'm not sure if this bit is right)

```
test_map <- projectRaster(HB_map, crs ="+init=epsg:27200")
```

I then check the data projections are consistent

```
crs(Regional_boundary_sf_poly)
```

[1] "+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +units=m +no_defs"

```
crs(test_map)
```

+init=epsg:27200 +proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +datum=nzgd49
+units=m +no_defs +ellps=intl +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993

Now I apply my mask:

```
Library(raster)
test_map_mask <- raster::mask(test,Regional_boundary_sf_poly,inverse=FALSE,updatevalue=NA, updadateNA=FALSE)
```

And check the results

```
tmap::qtm(test_map_mask)
```

It all seems to work except the map colours no longer look like the original "stamen-terrain" but are instead different shades of orange". How do adjust the settings to make the map look like the original but with the mask?

Thanks for you help.
Kind regards,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

## NEW ANSWER

Try to get the tiles with `cartography::getTiles`, it seems to work. Note that you should have `sf v0.9-0` and `cartography v2.4-0` installed, both recently updated on **CRAN**. A complete list of tiles serves available on `getTiles`[here](http://riatelab.github.io/cartography/docs/reference/getTiles.html).

```r
library(sf)
library(cartography)
library(dplyr)

nz <- spData::nz %>% st_transform(27200)

#Get tile
HB_map <- cartography::getTiles(nz, type = "Stamen.Terrain")

class(HB_map)
#> [1] "RasterBrick"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "raster"

st_crs(HB_map)$proj4string
#> [1] "+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +units=m +no_defs "
st_crs(nz)$proj4string
#> [1] "+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +units=m +no_defs "

library(raster)
test_map_mask <-
  raster::mask(
    HB_map,
    nz,
  )

#tmap
tmap::qtm(test_map_mask)
#> Warning: replacing previous import 'sf::st_make_valid' by
#> 'lwgeom::st_make_valid' when loading 'tmap'
#> Numeric values of test_map_mask interpreted as RGB values with max.value = 255. Run tm_shape(test_map_mask) + tm_raster() to visualize the data.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## OLD ANSWER

You may want to check `getPngLayer` and `pngLayer` from `cartography`, basically with this you create a png file as a raster masked with a `sf` and plot it.

If your problem is the plotting,  `pngLayer` Is basically a wrapper of `raster::plotRGB`.

Extra ball is that you can get also Stamen Terrain using `getTiles` , also on `cartography`, but make sure you install the latest version (released today on CRAN).

Reprex:

```r
library(sf)
library(cartography)
library(dplyr)

HB_map <- spData::nz %>% getTiles(type = "Stamen.Terrain")
class(HB_map)
#> [1] "RasterBrick"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "raster"

Regional_boundary <- spData::nz  
st_crs(HB_map)$proj4string
#> [1] "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "
st_crs(Regional_boundary)$proj4string
#> [1] "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "

library(raster)

test_map_mask <-
  raster::mask(
    HB_map,
    Regional_boundary,
  )
#> Warning: st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for
#> that

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
tilesLayer(test_map_mask)
plot(st_geometry(Regional_boundary), border = "red", lwd=2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Vignette: https://dieghernan.github.io/cartographyvignette/

Source code: https://github.com/riatelab/cartography/blob/master/R/tilesLayer.R

[image]

Comment: Hi dieghernan, thanks for your answer.  It looks as though the problem is to do with the type of raster I'm trying to mask. The rasterbrick works okay but not so much the RasterLayer.  I found the maps with rasterbricks to be of lower resolution to the read_osm RasterLayer maps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by dieghrnan I can now get some example data, and the below now runs fine for me

```
library(sf)
library(cartography)
library(raster) 
library(spData) 

nz <- spData::nz
HB <- cartography::getTiles(nz, type = "Stamen.Terrain")
HB_mask <- raster::mask(HB, nz)
plotRGB(HB_mask)
```

If you want a projection:

```
test <- projectRaster(HB_mask, crs ="+init=epsg:27200")
# or perhaps
# test <- projectRaster(HB_mask, method="ngb", crs ="+init=epsg:27200")
plotRGB(test)
```

**old answer:**

At what step do you loose the colors? my guess is at projectRaster? I cannot get rJava to work so I cannot run this, but I would try

```
colortable(test_map_mask) <- colortable(HB_map)
tmap::qtm(test_map_mask)
```

Comment: That was so close - it changed the colour but didn't quite fix my issue...I think the issue is the type of raster I'm using.  I think the steps would work perfectly for something like a interpolation model but not for rasters like aerial photos etc.  :(